# Name for generalization of bivariate weighted-homogeneous polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, terminology

A polynomial $f = \sum_j c_j X^{\alpha_j}Y^{\beta_j}\in\mathbb K[X,Y]$ is said *weighted-homogeneous* if there exist $p$, $q$ and $d$ (where $p$ and $q$ are not both $0$) such that $p\alpha_j+q\beta_j=d$ for all $j$. Graphically, this means that the [Newton polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) of $f$ is contained in a line.

Weighted-homogeneity can be generalized to $n$-variate polynomials: $f = \sum_j c_j X_1^{\alpha_{1,j}}\cdots X_n^{\alpha_{n,j}}$ is weighted-homogeneous if there exist $p_1$, ..., $p_n$, not all zero, and $d$ such that $p_1\alpha_{1,j}+\dotsb+p_n\alpha_{n,j}=d$ for all $j$. This corresponds to $f$ having a Newton polytope contained in a hyperplane (that is, a $(n-1)$-dimensional Newton polytope).

Now, is there a name for this other generalization: $f\in\mathbb K[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ is **[please insert name here]** if its Newton polytope is one-dimensional. Note that these means that there exist $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb Z^n$ and a univariate polynomial $g\in\mathbb K[Z]$ such that $f(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)=X^{\alpha} g( X^{\beta})$ (where $X^\alpha$ denotes the product $X_1^{\alpha_1}\dotsb X_n^{\alpha_n}$, and similarly for $X^\beta$).

Comment: Dear @Bruno, if possible, can you please add an appropriate top-level tag to your question (see also https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow). That may make your question easier to find by the people who can answer it. A top-level tag is one with a two-letter code and a dot at the beginning. Perhaps 'ac.commutative-algebra' or 'ag.algebraic-geometry' could be appropriate for this question. Thank you.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: Part of the difficulty to find the correct terminology comes from the fact that I do not know exactly in which area such kind of polynomials may have been studied. I'd use the tags 'ac.commutative-algebra', 'ag.algebraic-geometry' and 'ra.rings-and-algebra'. If it is not too much, I'll add them.

Comment: I add the two top-level tags you mention, that may be the most relevant ones indeed.